# How to Draw TextView on Canvas in android..?

Tags: android

How to Draw TextView on Canvas in android..?

We have `Canvas.DrawBitmap()`, `Canvas.drawText()`. Do we have any Method in Canvas which takes TextView as a parameter or any other method to display TextView on Canvas?

Actually, I have a alphabet in TextView and I have to make drawing on that alphabet which is in canvas.

Please suggest anything....Thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 56):

You can't draw a Textview directly, but you can put it in a layout and draw the layout. Something like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);

TextView textView = new TextView(context); 
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView.setText("Hello world");
layout.addView(textView);

layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

// To place the text view somewhere specific:
//canvas.translate(0, 0);

layout.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: about the measure() call, I had more success using MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) instead of canvas.getWidth() (and same for height).

Comment: is it possible to make the TextView clickable? I am adding an onClickListener but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Doesn't TextView have a draw method that takes a canvas? Is it a no-op?

Comment: I already have a textview in my XML file and I want to apply canvas on it.

Comment: how to display in center of screen

Answer (score 3):

May be you need to use `StaticLayout`. It can draw formatted text, manages word wrapping and so on. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class which will extend Textview. After that override onDraw method. This method provides you to draw your textview tha way you like it