# Android scrollable textview on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, textview, scrollable

I would like to have a scrollable textview on a canvas.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242757/how-to-draw-textview-on-canvas-in-android) describes how to draw a textview onto a canvas and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android) describes how to make a textview scrollable. If I combine them in the most straightforward way (i.e. just add function calls `setMaxLines` and `setMovementMethod`) it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? The post about using a layout to draw into a Canvas seems unnecessary in most circumstances. I have a different suggestion...

Extend TextView and provide the Canvas to it as a member (pass it in a constructor or set method). Then override the draw method and use the member Canvas to pass to super.draw. Then do whatever else you want with the Canvas.

Or, if you aren't doing anything too crazy, simply extend TextView, override onDraw, and use the Canvas passed there to do your drawing. Only in very unusual circumstances should you really need to draw the View into a separate Canvas.

Comment: I have a class `MyPainter` which is instantiated from a class `MyView` (which extends View). MyPainter has a `draw(Canvas canvas)` function (called from `MyView`'s `onDraw`) and shall paint a scrollable textview onto the canvas. It seems, however, that the textview does not receive any touch events.

Comment: Again, I don't think you are doing things properly. It sounds to me like the `TextView` should be a child of `MyView`. You shouldn't need to draw the `TextView` yourself. If it is allowed to participate in the view hierarchy normally, it will receive events and it will be scrollable if you set it's properties appropriately. If you need to do extra drawing on top of the `TextView`, extend it like I suggested.

Comment: The `TextView` is not supposed to be related to `MyView`. `MyView`  has a member which paints on its canvas, i.e. `MyPainter` (which is a base class for different painters). So `MyPainter` shall be responsible for drawing on `MyView`s canvas. One element that shall be painted on the canvas is a `TextView`.

Comment: I'm not convinced, but suit yourself. Without seeing any code, I would guess your only chance to handle touch events will be through `MyView` since it seems to be the only thing properly hooked up to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Well the idea was to provide a view with several (alternative) painters which can then paint on the view's canvas. As long as I only use `Canvas`' draw functions like `drawCircle`, everything works fine. Even drawing a `TextView` works but there is the problem when I want it to be scrollable (supposely because of the touch events)