# Can't draw editText in android canvas

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add an editText box to my android project. This project is done almost entirely with Java (barely any xml), so I would like to know how to get this done in Java. My current implementation which is getting a runtime error is as follows:

```
public class MainMenu extends View{
    EditText editText;

    public MainMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
        EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        editText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        editText.setText("My Text");
        editText.setWidth(180);         
        editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        editText.draw(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong and possibly offer a solution using Java?

Comment: EditText is view. You are trying to draw view inside view. Wtf?

Comment: I am trying to add a textbox that when clicked it would open up a number screen so that you can enter numbers. Googling how to do this led me to a topic that recommended using EditText. How else should I approach this then?

Comment: so extend EditText,  not View

Comment: This is wrong in So many ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
```

Your "editText" will be null in the onDraw method i think

```
editText = new EditText(context);
```

Please let us know when u resolved it

Comment: I'm dumb for not noticing that. That stopped the runtime error. Now I'm having the problem of not seeing anything. Tried setting the editText visibility, enabling the requestFocus, setting a height/position. Nothing I add is making it visible.

Comment: You should read on how views work. Now you should probable accept this answer because your first question is why do you have an exception thrown.

Comment: i found something :) u have to put it in a layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242757/how-to-draw-textview-on-canvas-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```java
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
```

You can find this in the top-right of the design xml file. Good luck!